# Удаление перекрестных столбцов Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Совершенно простейшая задача, но столкнулся с невозможностью ее решения.
Есть столбец с списком доменов под буквой А ;
Есть столбец с списком доменов под буквой I;

Нужно получить список доменов из столбца под буквой A, перед этим удалив из столбца А, все домены, которые уже есть в столбце I.
Пытался это сделать с помощью =query(A:I, "Select A where A != I"), но оно сравнивает явно не так как ожидается, убирая значения только если они находятся на одной строке.

[image: Скрин из таблицы с доменами прилагается]

Answer (score 0):

В свободный столбец, начиная со строки 2 (предполагается, что в первой строке заголовки таблицы):

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЕТЕСЛИ(A2;I:I);0;A2)
```

Получаем столбец с доменами, которых нет в столбце `I`, и нулевыми значениями (в строках с теми доменами, которые найдены в столбце `I`).

Далее заменить формулы на значения (выделить диапазон, копировать, вставить как значения), отсортировать столбец, чтобы убрать нули из диапазона найденных доменов..